# Can I share a Fallout 4 save file between multiple people on PS4?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

I want to be able to make progress in Fallout 4 (PS4) and then send the save file to a friend so they can continue.

After they are done they will send it back and so on.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Between PS and Xbox systems, very unlikely.  It may be possible within the same system (e.g. a friend on PS4 using your PS4 save) - but you probably need to break the console's terms and conditions by using a third party tool to reassign the save to another account (at least, that is the method on the Xbox 360).  I don't even know if you can get to the save files on the xbox one because it appears they save/load from "the cloud".

Comment: Are you asking about transferring from one platform type to another, as @camelCase apparently read things? I read this as asking about transferring from either one Xbox to another or one PS4 to another.

Comment: sorry about the confusion - I have updated to include PS4 only. The only reason I said "PS4/Xbox One" was because the word "console" tends to confuse players for the command console. In the end it was just better to specify my particular use case of PS4. @DangerZone - I can't find any major logical differences - should I delete my question?

Comment: @kraftydevil - If the answer on that question helps you (and based on the comments of the OP's findingd it sounds like "No, it wont work"), it might be best to delete. If there is something that wasn't answered for you though, it might be worth it to edit that info in and keep open. Up to you.

Comment: Don't delete it either way. We can just close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @DCShannon - only because the other question's answer got an upvote. It did not have one earlier, and I was not going to upvote an answer simply to enable the duplicate flagging.

Comment: I'm stuck with a dialogue saying "That solved my problem!" and "No, my question is different" since neither are true. The one answer was shown to not work so it doesn't solve my problem. At the same time, my question is logically the same. Definitely ok with closing this.

Comment: @DangerZone I've never understood the requirement that there be an *answer* to close a *question* as a duplicate. I actually would have preferred to close the other one as a duplicate of this one, since this question is worded a little more broadly.

Comment: @DCShannon - Agreed. Pretty worthless requirement if you ask me.